# Comparing and counting bits blockwise

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have a very specific problem and I'd like to get your opinion on it:

Given a 32-bit integer, I want to know how many 2-bit-blocks are less or equal to 00, 01 or 10. I **don't** know the 2-bit-pattern I'm comparing the integer to at compile-time.

```
00 01 10 11 01 11 00 10 ... // 4 blocks <= 01
```

So far I'm using if-constructs and create a bit mask applying to the integer and calling `__builtin_popcount()`. Here is an example on how to check `word` for `<= 01` on 32-bit integers.

```
__builtin_popcount(~(word | 0x55555555))
```

Unfortunately those case distinctions (3 in total) cost a lot of time and I would like to speed things up. Iterating over the integer and comparing blockwise is probably a worse idea. Any chance I can improve it further?

Comment: Search the internet for "bit twiddling hacks".

Comment: `__builtin_popcount(~(word | 0x55555555))` seems very efficient. Why do you lose a lot of time picking between the 3 cases?

Comment: Nice trick, though you can't use it for the 00 comparisson.

Answer (score 2):

Store all your 2bit bitmasks in an array. 
Cache the 32-bit integer.

For each 2bit block of the 32bit integer:

Restore the cached integer to the temporary integer.

<< to clear the more significant bits, then bitshift >> 30 bits such that the bits you desire to examine are the two least significant bits in the register.

For each mask, Bitwise AND. Cache result to some subset of previously allocated array.

Loop, changing the bitshift as necessary to obtain a distinct mask.

In the first iteration, << 30 bits,  >> 30 bits.
In the second iteration, << 28 bits, >> 30 bits.

Comment: How do you cache the integer?

Comment: Store it in some variable. Int is implementation-defined but if the programmer has a lot of memory to use, (un)signed long long would do the trick.

Comment: Wouldn't the value already be stored in some variable? I'm trying to learn and I find the terminology confusing. So if caching=="Store it in some variable", then what does "Restore the cached integer to the temporary integer." mean? Seems like we're just copying values then? No CPU or other cache is directly implied? Why copy it in the first place? How does this answer provide a more efficient solution than `__builtin_popcount(~(word | 0x55555555))` along with two other cases?

Comment: Slight tweak to that: If this is supported on your compiler and platform, `#include <cstdint>` and then use `int32_t` or since this is an exercise in bit-twiddling use `uint32_t` and ignore the sign. This way you get no surprises with the size of the integer. It will be 32 bits or you'll get a compiler error saying 32 bits can't be done.

Comment: @flatmouse Yes, but the 32bit integer passed to the function will be mutated by the bitshifts, regardless of how it is stored, so it must be copied. I cannot confirm that the solution will be more efficient but certain architectures (ARM, for one) can do a bitshift while moving a value from memory into a register. The hardware architecture can be the determining factor with regard to how performant low-level code is. It is possible that __builtin_popcount may be more performant on some architectures.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest possible way to compute this at run-time (theoretically) is to pre-compute the result.

Warning, this may take 'some time' to compile...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <utility>

constexpr int bits_less(unsigned int sample, int cmp)
{
    auto samples = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits;
    auto tot = 0;
    while (samples)
    {
        auto acc = sample & 0x3;
        if (acc <= cmp)
            ++tot;
        sample >>= 2;
        samples -= 2;
    }
    return tot;

}

struct less_table
{
    constexpr less_table()
    : less_table(std::make_index_sequence<entries>())
    {}

    template<std::size_t...Is>
    constexpr less_table(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    : less_tab {
        { bits_less(Is, 0), bits_less(Is, 1), bits_less(Is, 2) }
    }
    {}

    constexpr int get(unsigned int sample, int pattern) const
    {
        return less_tab[sample][pattern];
    }

    static constexpr std::size_t entries = std::size_t(std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()) + 1;
    int less_tab[entries][3];
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << bits_less(0x34237645, 0x01) << std::endl;

    constexpr less_table lt;
    std::cout << lt.get(0x34237645, 0x01) << std::endl;
}
```

results may vary:

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: Killed: 9
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: note: diagnostic msg:
********************

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/h0/qp9lmbgs3fx_6gc9czqv8wh80000gp/T/less_tab-fb5e34.cpp
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/h0/qp9lmbgs3fx_6gc9czqv8wh80000gp/T/less_tab-fb5e34.sh
clang: note: diagnostic msg:

********************
```

enjoy :)

Comment: Well I'm not sure I believe the premise to begin with. OPs solution would have a latency of 5 on Haswell, the minimum for a load is 4 and it already becomes 5 just by using indexing, and realistically you can add a cache miss on top of that.

Comment: @harold but not portable... not that mine is portable either, or even possible :)

Answer (score 1):

With appropriate bit manipulation each of the three cases can be efficiently handled:

```
#include <iostream> 

int main()
{
    unsigned int value{0xE4E79EEF};

    unsigned int A{~(value | 0x55555555)};
    unsigned int B{~((~value) | 0x55555555)};
    unsigned int C{(~(value | 0xAAAAAAAA)) << 1};
    unsigned int D{(~((~value) | 0xAAAAAAAA)) << 1};

    int lt00{16 - __builtin_popcount(B|D)};
    int lt01{__builtin_popcount(A)};
    int lt10{__builtin_popcount(A|C)};

    std::cout << "Original bit pattern: 11 10 01 00 11 10 01 11 10 01 11 10 11 10 11 11\n";
    std::cout << "Number of 2-bit blocks less than or equal to 00: " << lt00 << " block(s)\n";
    std::cout << "Number of 2-bit blocks less than or equal to 01: " << lt01 << " block(s)\n";
    std::cout << "Number of 2-bit blocks less than or equal to 10: " << lt10 << " block(s)\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
Original bit pattern: 11 10 01 00 11 10 01 11 10 01 11 10 11 10 11 11
Number of 2-bit blocks less than or equal to 00: 1 block(s)
Number of 2-bit blocks less than or equal to 01: 4 block(s)
Number of 2-bit blocks less than or equal to 10: 9 block(s)
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47c2a3f8b8041344)